# How to use an interface as a parameter when i try to use reflection in java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, interface, methods

I have an interface which is generic:

```
public interface DataTable < T > {

}
```

And I have a Factory class returning an instance of my class that implements `DataTable<T>`

```
public class DataTableFactory<T> {

    public DataTable<T> getInstance() { 
             return dataTableImpl();
    }
}
```

And another class named as list which has a method `public void setDataTable(DataTable < T > dataTable)`

Now i just want to invoke this method by using java reflection:

```
Helper helper = new Helper(operationsFile);
Class c = null;
c = Class.forName(helper.getClassName("list"));
Object t = c.newInstance();

Method methodSetDataTable = c.getDeclaredMethod("setDataTable", paramTypes);
```

In this example I couldn't find how to get `paramTypes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the method declaration for `setDataTable`, I expect the param type will be just `DataTable.class`.

Comment: In fact, type erasure ensures that the param type can't be anything more specific.